# Error al borrar una Base de Datos SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

Buenas tengo un programa java que me crea una base de datos sqlite cuando finalizo el programa quiero que se elimine la base de datos para que no quede registro de ella en el ordenador. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void borrarSQLite() {

    try {
            con.getS().executeUpdate("DROP DATABASE peval2");
            System.out.println("BD SQLite eliminada correctamente");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("ERROR AL ELIMINAR LA BD SQLite");
    }
}
```

He probado a ejecutar la consulta directamente en SQLite y me dice lo siguiente:

```
near "DATABASE": syntax error: drop DATABASE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Cómo descarto una base de datos SQLite?

Las personas acostumbradas a trabajar con otras bases de datos están acostumbradas a tener un `DROP DATABASE`, pero en SQLite no hay un comando similar.

¿La razón? En SQLite no hay un "servidor de base de datos": SQLite es una base de datos integrada, y toda su base de datos está contenida en un archivo. Por lo tanto, no hay necesidad de un comando "soltar base de datos" de SQLite, todo lo que debe hacer para eliminar la base de datos es eliminar el archivo de base de datos SQLite al que estaba accediendo

Comment: Gracias no lo sabia , ahora me las tendré que apañar para crear un método que me borre el archivo automáticamente.